# Access the motion tracking camera on Tango phone

Tags: android, computer-vision, google-project-tango, tango

Is there an api to read the image data from the motion tracking camera on Tango phones? By motion tracking camera, I meant the global shutter camera that is used to do feature extraction and tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tango API. For more information and access the Tango API, here is a useful [address](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/overview)